# Swap sublists in a List<MyObject>

Tags: java, list, swap, sublist

Is there an easy method to swap 2 sublists in a List.
Example:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11] --> [0 1 8 9 10 4 5 6 7 2 3 11]
  --> Sublist1= [2 3]
  --> Sublist2= [8 9 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with indexes, this can be done by using subList function multiple files and by creating a new list object as shown below...

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(myList.subList(0, 4));
newList.addAll(myList.subList(7, 9));
newList.addAll(myList.subList(4, 7));
newList.addAll(myList.subList(9, 12));
```

Here we are swapping from index 4 to 6 with indexes 7 to 8

If you want to do it only using the elements, first use the elements to find indexes of subList and use the above procedure.

Don't get confused with endIndex of subList function... 
fromIndex - low endpoint (inclusive) of the subList
toIndex - high endpoint (exclusive) of the subList 
so if you mention 7,9 in the subList function it means all elements from index 7 till elements below index 9.

Comment: It should also be noted that you are creating a new list, rather than doing an in-place swap of the elements of the existing list.

Comment: I still think using swap is a better option, but this solution should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, but not short:

```
  static <E> void swapSubList(List<E> list, int first1,int last1, int first2, int last2){
        for (int i=first1, j=first2; i<=last1 || j<=last2; i++, j++) {
            if(i<=last1 && j<=last2) {
                Collections.swap(list, i, j);
            }
            else if (i>last1){
                E temp = list.remove(j);
                list.add(i, temp);
            }
            else {
                E temp = list.remove(i);
                list.add(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to create a new collection.

Comment: this is exactly what I was talking about :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Util.Collections.swap

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List, int, int)

Comment: This is good method, but this only works when number of elements in the from and to sublists are of same size. and has to be done for individual elements.

Comment: You can call swap function multiple times for pair of elements to do anything you want. You can still keep using the same List instead of creating a new List...this is just an option.

Comment: I would love to see the solution using multiple swaps. :)

Comment: But how do we solve when the sublists to be swapped are not of same size, the logic gets complicated.

Comment: First swap 2--8, 3--9, 4--10, then delete 4 (using index), and add 4 back after 10 (using index). You will also need to use java.util.remove and java.util.add

Comment: Seems like a lot of work. gonna doe it with sublists. Not very neat but it will work..